# You know sometimes when a button or picture is pressed,

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-imagebutton

You know sometimes when a button or picture is pressed, and the image gets smaller, then when you release it, it goes back to normal. How would i do that in android studio with an image-button

Answer (score 0):

You can have an `onclicklistener` or `onlongPresslistener` on the button, when it presses you can reduce the size of the `imageview` that you are using to display the image and when the button is released you can display the original.

Answer (score 0):

create one xml file in drawable like this and set as a background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/YourHoverImage" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/NormalImage" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/YourHoverImage" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

you can do like this.